# R - Vectorization function

Tags: r, function, apply, mapply

---- Hello everyone, my problem is that I have the next winning combination and 3 "tickets".

```
winner <- c("L","L",rep("X",12))

[1] "L" "L" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"

combinations

   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14
1    L    L    L    L    L    L    L    L    L     L     L     L     L     L
2    X    L    L    L    L    L    L    L    L     L     L     L     L     L
3    V    L    L    L    L    L    L    L    L     L     L     L     L     L

dput(combinations)

structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("L", "X", "V"
), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var10 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var11 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var12 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor"), Var14 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"X", "V"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", 
"Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", "Var9", "Var10", "Var11", 
"Var12", "Var13", "Var14"), out.attrs = structure(list(dim = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), dimnames = structure(list(
    Var1 = c("Var1=L", "Var1=X", "Var1=V"), Var2 = c("Var2=L", 
    "Var2=X", "Var2=V"), Var3 = c("Var3=L", "Var3=X", "Var3=V"
    ), Var4 = c("Var4=L", "Var4=X", "Var4=V"), Var5 = c("Var5=L", 
    "Var5=X", "Var5=V"), Var6 = c("Var6=L", "Var6=X", "Var6=V"
    ), Var7 = c("Var7=L", "Var7=X", "Var7=V"), Var8 = c("Var8=L", 
    "Var8=X", "Var8=V"), Var9 = c("Var9=L", "Var9=X", "Var9=V"
    ), Var10 = c("Var10=L", "Var10=X", "Var10=V"), Var11 = c("Var11=L", 
    "Var11=X", "Var11=V"), Var12 = c("Var12=L", "Var12=X", "Var12=V"
    ), Var13 = c("Var13=L", "Var13=X", "Var13=V"), Var14 = c("Var14=L", 
    "Var14=X", "Var14=V")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", 
"Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", "Var9", "Var10", "Var11", 
"Var12", "Var13", "Var14"))), .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

The tickets' price is showen next

```
price

  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14
1 2.48 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16
2 3.28 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16
3 3.16 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16

dput(price)

structure(list(Var1 = c(2.48, 3.28, 3.16), Var2 = c(1.79, 1.79, 
1.79), Var3 = c(2.99, 2.99, 2.99), Var4 = c(2.31, 2.31, 2.31), 
    Var5 = c(4.03, 4.03, 4.03), Var6 = c(2.1, 2.1, 2.1), Var7 = c(2.71, 
    2.71, 2.71), Var8 = c(2.22, 2.22, 2.22), Var9 = c(2.7, 2.7, 
    2.7), Var10 = c(2.94, 2.94, 2.94), Var11 = c(2.01, 2.01, 
    2.01), Var12 = c(2.16, 2.16, 2.16), Var13 = c(3.41, 3.41, 
    3.41), Var14 = c(2.16, 2.16, 2.16)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", 
"Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", "Var7", "Var8", "Var9", "Var10", 
"Var11", "Var12", "Var13", "Var14"), out.attrs = structure(list(
    dim = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), dimnames = structure(list(Var1 = c("Var1=2.48", "Var1=3.28", 
    "Var1=3.16"), Var2 = c("Var2=1.79", "Var2=4.04", "Var2=4.55"
    ), Var3 = c("Var3=2.99", "Var3=3.38", "Var3=2.54"), Var4 = c("Var4=2.31", 
    "Var4=3.39", "Var4=3.36"), Var5 = c("Var5=4.03", "Var5=3.22", 
    "Var5=2.14"), Var6 = c("Var6=2.10", "Var6=3.77", "Var6=3.60"
    ), Var7 = c("Var7=2.71", "Var7=3.22", "Var7=2.93"), Var8 = c("Var8=2.22", 
    "Var8=3.56", "Var8=3.47"), Var9 = c("Var9=2.70", "Var9=3.66", 
    "Var9=2.65"), Var10 = c("Var10=2.94", "Var10=3.30", "Var10=2.65"
    ), Var11 = c("Var11=2.01", "Var11=3.61", "Var11=4.09"), Var12 = c("Var12=2.16", 
    "Var12=3.15", "Var12=4.19"), Var13 = c("Var13=3.41", "Var13=3.43", 
    "Var13=2.27"), Var14 = c("Var14=2.16", "Var14=3.78", "Var14=3.43"
    )), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6", 
    "Var7", "Var8", "Var9", "Var10", "Var11", "Var12", "Var13", 
    "Var14"))), .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I did the next formula to calculate the price of a certain ticket (it's an unrealistic price but my book says this)

```
myfunction2 <- function(x,y){
 ifelse(sum((x==winner))>=2,prod(((x==winner)*y)+((x==winner)<=0)*1),return(1))
                             }

  myfunction2(combinations[1,],price[1,])
  [1] 4.4392

  myfunction2(combinations[2,],price[2,])
  [1] 1.0000

  myfunction2(combinations[3,],price[3,])
  [1] 1.0000
```

The formulas it's correct, in the first case the price is (2.48*1.79)=4.4392, in the second and third case the answer are 1 because I need at least two correct answer to pay more that 1.

When I try to "vectorize" the formula, answers are incorrect

```
R3 <- apply(combinations,1,myfunction2,y=price)

R3
    1        2        3 
  595.0378   1.00000  1.00000
```

I can solve the problem with a for loop, but I have `3^14` combinations and it's very slow, I try with `mapply`, but I have the same problem (incorrect answers)

Any help is welcome, thank you so much

Comment: Your code does not match your results. Because the second and third rows do not have two matches they should be 0, not the 1 that you have listed. Please edit your question, fix your code, change your data to be easier to use (e.g., use `dput(price)` as well as for the other variables). (BTW, everything inside `prod(...)` can be handled much easier with `ifelse(...)`.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes, sorry I'm wrong. I did not know the function `pdut()`, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to figure out why the `apply` method is not working is to manually insert a `browser()` in your function and see what it is actually seeing for arguments. Using your data from above, here is your function with the added line:

```
myfunction2 <- function(x,y){
  browser()
  if (sum((x==winner))>=2) {
    return( prod( ((x == winner) * price) + (( x == winner) == 0) * 1) )
  } else {
    return(1)
  }
}

apply(combinations,1,myfunction2,price)
# Called from: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
# debug at #3: if (sum((x == winner)) >= 2) {
#     return(prod(((x == winner) * price) + ((x == winner) == 0) * 
#         1))
# } else {
#     return(1)
# }
# Browse[2]>
x
#  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6  Var7  Var8  Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14 
#   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"   "L"
```

So far so good.

```
# Browse[2]>
y
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14
# 1 2.48 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16
# 2 3.28 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16
# 3 3.16 1.79 2.99 2.31 4.03  2.1 2.71 2.22  2.7  2.94  2.01  2.16  3.41  2.16
```

There's part of your problem: it is seeing *all* of `price` on each call, and your function doesn't know to check for this.

BTW: you misread my recommendation on the use of `ifelse`. Though the way you are using it is working, it is incorrect and will bite you later. I suggest you google the difference between `ifelse` and the traditional `if ... else`. Long-story-short: `ifelse` needs to assume that the lengths of its three arguments are identical (or easily recycled), so when you are testing a single thing (`sum(...)>=2`, its first argument), then you should be using `if ... else`.

Additionally, since `combinations[1,]` technically is returning a data.frame, you should unlist it to deal consistently with other things. (Same for `price`.) Consider this as an alternative to your function:

```
myfunction3 <- function(x,y){
  i <- (unlist(x) == winner)
  if (sum(i) >= 2) prod(ifelse(i, unlist(y), 1)) else 1
}
myfunction3(combinations[1,], price[1,])
# [1] 4.4392
myfunction3(combinations[2,], price[2,])
# [1] 1
myfunction3(combinations[3,], price[3,])
# [1] 1
```

Lastly, I'm a huge fan of avoiding [side-effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)). Something similar to this is reaching out of a function's scope ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)) to get at a variable in a parent environment or namespace. Though it works, it can be problematic. I'll fix that by passing the value of `winner` in the function arguments.

```
myfunction4 <- function(x,y,w){
  i <- (unlist(x) == w)
  if (sum(i) >= 2) prod(ifelse(i, unlist(y), 1)) else 1
}
```

Back to the original problem of getting all of `price` at once. Though it is certainly possible to warp this to use `mapply`, I think it's the only one of the `*apply` functions that could easily be applied to this problem, and even then it will take a little massaging and transformation of the data.frames. Instead, I recommend using something like this:

```
myfunction5 <- function(comb, pr, win) {
  i <- (unlist(comb) == win)
  if (sum(i) >= 2) prod(ifelse(i, unlist(pr), 1)) else 1
}
```

Finally, we're able to do something like this:

```
sapply(1:nrow(combinations),
       function(i, comb, pr, win) myfunction5(comb[i,], pr[i,], win),
       combinations, price, winner)
# [1] 4.4392 1.0000 1.0000
```

In this case, `i` is merely an index to the rows within `combinations` and `price`. Though it seems pedantic, writing functions that are completely self-sufficient (do not reach "outside" of their space for a variable that was not provided to it) will generally produce stronger, more "defensive" programs.

**NOTE**: all of this is still dodging one large potential issue here: it is really risky practice to use `apply(x, 1, ...)` when `x` is a data.frame. Though it works here (only because each of your data.frames are completely homogeneous), it will bite you when you least expect it. The problem is that data.frames allow you to add a column that is a different class from the others, so if you added a column of strings to your `price` variable for whatever reason, none of this will work anymore.

Also, this tends to break down a little if you don't have some sanity checks. For instance, enforcing the implicit requirement that `combinations` and `price` must have identical dimensions, and `winner` must be the same length as the number of columns in the other two.

Comment: Wow!, your answer was excellent, thanks for everything.